# How to catch key from keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, key, try-catch

I have a problem. I need write a C# program 
Input: Allows the user to enter multiple lines of text, press Ctrl + Enter to finish typing 
Output: Standardize by, rearranging lines in the right order of increasing time.

I was tried but I don't know how to catch Ctrl + Enter from keyboard:

I expect the output like
Example:

```
“Created at 28/02/2018 10:15:35 AM by Andy.
Updated at 03/03/2018 02:45:10 PM by Mark
Clear name at 02/03/2018 11:34:05 AM by Andy”
```

DateTime is needed  rearranging

Comment: What platform do you use (console, Forms, WPF, WUP...)? If applicable, what control do you use?

Comment: I use Console platform

Comment: I try this way but I can find how to catch Ctrl+Enter:  String lines;
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
            do
            {
                lines = Console.ReadLine();
                if(info.Key == ConsoleKey.Clear)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lines) || info.Key != ConsoleKey.Clear);

Comment: You need to create your own input system to override the default console handler. You will create a loop to `ReadKey()` and process all desired key codes like arrows, backspace, delete, letters, numbers, and the Ctrl+Enter... So for each key, you reinject to the console what you want to process, moving the caret, deleting char, and ending the process. Try to write something with a `while (true) { ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(true); process input ... }`. You need to manage the result buffer as well. That's fun. [.NET Console Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console)

Comment: `if ( input.Modifiers.HasFlag(ConsoleModifiers.Control) && input.Key.HasFlag(ConsoleKey.Enter) ) break;` and you do the same thing for all keys you want to process. Having a CurrentIndex in a string buffer that moves/del/add char as user press arrows, backspace, delete, enter alone or letters/numbers and so on, while updating the display. You can set colors too.

Comment: Oh it works!!! Thank my friends

Comment: @OlivierRogier How to rearranging lines in the right order of increasing time?

Comment: What means "rearranging lines in the right order of increasing time"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own input system to override the default console handler.

You will create a loop to `ReadKey(true)` and process all desired key codes like arrows, backspace, delete, letters, numbers, and the Ctrl+Enter...

So for each key, you reinject to the console what you want to process, moving the caret, deleting char, and ending the process.

You need to manage the result buffer as well.

That's fun.

[.NET Console Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console)

Here is a sample:

```
void GetConsoleUserInput()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter something:");
  var result = new List<char>();
  int index = 0;
  while ( true )
  {
    var input = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if ( input.Modifiers.HasFlag(ConsoleModifiers.Control) 
      && input.Key.HasFlag(ConsoleKey.Enter) )
      break;
    if ( char.IsLetterOrDigit(input.KeyChar) )
    {
      if (index == result.Count)
        result.Insert(index++, input.KeyChar);
      else
        result[index] = input.KeyChar;
      Console.Write(input.KeyChar);
    }
    else
    if ( input.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && index > 0 )
    {
      index--;
      Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
    }
    // And so on
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("You entered: ");
  Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(result));
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

For multiline, the result buffer and index can be:

```
var result = new Dictionary<int, List<char>>();
```

And instead of index you can use:

```
int posX;
int posY;
```

So that is:

```
result[posY][posX];
```

Don't forget to update posX matching the line length when using up and down arrows.

Where it gets complicated, it's the management of the width of the console and the wrapping...

Have a great job!