# Can I use a while for control time like this?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need a timer to read a data by console for a certain time. I thought this was correct but it seems not. Some help please?

```
while ((DateTime.Now - initTime).Seconds <= limitTime)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var timeLimit = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15); // 15 sec
var dateStart = DateTime.Now;
var inputs = new List<string>();

while ( DateTime.Now - dateStart <= timeLimit )
  inputs.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

We use a `TimeSpan` to set the allowed time.

And since the substraction of two dates is a `TimeSpan`, we compare it to the allowed time while adding the input strings to a list.

The list is added for the example and you can manage the inputs in the loop or outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! but it seems that it doesn't work neither, the readline stops everything and I need the time to run even if the user does not enter anything in the console and go out the while when the time is up, not pressing enter :( maybe i need a thread.. and sorry for my english, im from spain... :)

Comment: Indeed, the console is blocked on the last readline called even if the time is over, but it stops after the user press enter. To have a fine input system, you may implement a hand-made console readline replacement by catching all keys and manage them such as letters, digits, arrows, backspace, delete, enter and so on... So this can be stopped exactly on timeout. I don't know if using a thread can help to solve this and you may try that and when the time is out you kill the thread.

Comment: This may help you: [How to create a custom command line user input method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109201/how-to-catch-key-from-keyboard-in-c-sharp/58109562#58109562). You can replace `ReadKey` by [Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.read) and manage the int result to have a realtime control of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, here is the function in case someone needs it. Thanks Oliver for your help!

```
 public static List<string> answerRange(byte maxTime)
        {
            TimeSpan maxT = new TimeSpan(0, 0, maxTime);
            DateTime initTime = DateTime.Now;
            List<string> userAnswers = new List<string>();
            while ((DateTime.Now - initTime) <= maxT)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
                    if (key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userAnswers.Add(key.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }


            return userAnswers;
        }
```